# Protractor Get count of all items in a drop list

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to get the count of all the options in a dropdown list. Below is the code that I think should work, but it does not

```
let elements_count  = await $$('#directClassBased > option').count();
console.log('\nThe length of the elements are'+ await elements_count+' \n');
```

The code returns the count as 0. How can it be fixed?

the html related to the dropbox is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><select _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="dcbsId" id="directClassBased">
        <!---->
        <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="0: C92AB645-9485-4A15-8F49-5412D1639962">Addison</option>
        <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="1: A85A556D-ABCA-44E5-80A5-9AF313E161FC">Dundalk</option>
        ....
        ....
    </select></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the double `$$` in your code: `$$('#directClassBased > option').count()`

Comment: remove the `await`  from `await elements_count`

Comment: Does this dropdown really exist in the `<head>` of your site or is this a typo?

Comment: @DublinDev the dropdown is not in the head.. the tag was copied when I copied the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below way

```
const elements_count  = element.all(by.css('#directClassBased > option'));
const drop = element(by.css('#directClassBased'));

await drop.click(); // to open the drop down 
await browser.sleep(1000);
console.log('\nThe length of the elements are'+ await elements_count.count() +' \n');
```